# ES6 : Redefine array value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got a const "skills" that's an array that contain from 0 to 31 skills :

```
skills : ["SKILL30", "SKILL31"]
```

I want to replace the output SKILL30 by its current name. (base on a JSON file, with FormattedMessage id="SKILL30" 
So my input will be :

```
skills : "Marketing", "Design"
```

Comment: please provide object value from JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be simple. Not mutating existing data but providing a new output:

```js
const skills = ["SKILL30", "SKILL31"];
const inputData = {"SKILL30": "Marketing", "SKILL31": "Design"};
const outputData = skills.map((skill) => inputData[skill]);

console.log(outputData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the JSON or the example metaObject, If you want the exact solution.

read the JSON into metaData in your case.

```js
let skills = ["SKILL30", "SKILL31"];
let metaData = [{
  id: "SKILL30",
  value: "Marketing"
},
{
  id: "SKILL31",
  value: "Design"
}];

let output = skills.map((skill => metaData.find(ele =>  ele.id === skill).value));
console.log(output)
```